# Issue with vividsolutions jts 'within' method

Tags: geospatial, jts

I am using com.vividsolutions.jts library for some spatial analysis. Following are the vertices of a polygon.

> [
>                 -91.23046875,
>                 51.069016659603896
>               ],
>               [
>                 -84.375,
>                 47.989921667414194
>               ],
>               [
>                 -80.595703125,
>                 49.89463439573421
>               ],
>               [
>                 -87.01171875,
>                 53.64463782485651
>               ],
>               [
>                 -91.23046875,
>                 51.069016659603896
>               ]

I am creating random points in close vicinity of this polygon and using following code to check whether point lies inside polygon or not:

```
point.within(polygon)
```

What I see is that for some points result is correct while for some points results are wrong.

For eg., following is the list of points and result of 'within' method for them:

> -82.5438973303955, 48.92064284689714 - result is inside even though points is outside
>
> -82.5397253036499, 48.91818466351969 - result is inside even though points is outside
>
> -82.54247188568115, 48.91942550176894 - result is inside even though points is outside
>
> -84.375,47.9892323448971 - outside(correct)

Why do I see this random behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I've just used QGis to plot your polygon and the points and the three you complain about are clearly in the polygon.

[image]

I did a bit more investigation on this and I suspect that you may have an issue with allowing/not allowing for the curve of the Earth.

First I switched into a flat projection (EPSG:3347) Stats Canada Lambert - this switches the results to match what you see. But if I densify the edges of your polygon (so that it gets reprojected all along the line rather than just at the corners) the results again match mine.

[image]

The pink is the naive projection and the yellow is the densified edge.

Here is the code if you want to play with it yourself:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.locationtech.jts.densify.Densifier;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon;
import org.opengis.geometry.MismatchedDimensionException;
import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.TransformException;

public class JTSWithin {
  static GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException, MismatchedDimensionException, TransformException {
    double c[][] = { { -91.23046875, 51.069016659603896 }, { -84.375, 47.989921667414194 },
        { -80.595703125, 49.89463439573421 }, { -87.01171875, 53.64463782485651 },
        { -91.23046875, 51.069016659603896 } };
    ArrayList<Coordinate> coords = new ArrayList<>();
    for (double pair[] : c) {
      Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(pair[0], pair[1]);
      coords.add(coord);
    }
    Polygon poly = gf.createPolygon(coords.toArray(new Coordinate[] {}));
    System.out.println(poly);

    Coordinate[] tests = { new Coordinate(-82.5438973303955, 48.92064284689714),
        new Coordinate(-82.5397253036499, 48.91818466351969), new Coordinate(-82.54247188568115, 48.91942550176894),
        new Coordinate(-84.375, 47.9892323448971) };

    for (Coordinate t : tests) {
      Point p = gf.createPoint(t);
      System.out.println(p);
      System.out.println(p.within(poly));
      System.out.println(poly.contains(p));
    }
    System.out.println("\nProjection\n");
    CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:3347");
    MathTransform wgsToCanada = CRS.findMathTransform(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, crs);
    Geometry dp = Densifier.densify(poly, 0.0001);
    Polygon pPoly = (Polygon) JTS.transform(dp, wgsToCanada);

    for (Coordinate t : tests) {
      Point p = gf.createPoint(t);
      Point tp = (Point) JTS.transform(p, wgsToCanada);
      System.out.println(tp);
      System.out.println(tp.within(pPoly));
      System.out.println(pPoly.contains(tp));
    }
  }
}
```